# Create a date in MDX (SSAS)

Tags: date, ssas, mdx

How it's possible to create a date in MDX for a given date ("4/6/2001 16:23:45").

Function now() returns the current date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function.

Comment: thanks, it's an awfully method "1/3/2001" it's the third of January or the third of March ?